# adding image in pdf using Django pisa: standard {% static 'path/to/image' %} do not working

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf, pisa

I try to implement pdf output using pisa following this tutorial: https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/html-template-to-pdf-in-django/

and it works except for images that are not displayed

I understand the problem deal with relative/absolute path between pisa and Django system but do not manage to resolve.
I read the solution in the xhtml2pdf document using link_callback method but it dosen work and have no error

If I pass the absolute url of images in context to my html template it works :

```
<img class="logo" src="{{ url }}" alt="logo alima">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the problem that `{% static %}` returns the path under the domain and when xhtml2pdf runs it doesn't know which domain to contact so this problem has several solutions

1. Add request.META['HOST'] to your image url
2. Adding a settings variable called 'PDF_BASE_URL'  and it to your image URL.

I like the second solution as you can set the value to localhost with the need to resolve the domain which is used by the users.